# Why regression output is omitted in Stata?

Tags: regression, stata

I am a bit confused of why I get omitted output in my regression results when I know for the fact that all of those dummy combinations are alive and well in my data set:

```
           |     Display
  Promotion|         0          1 |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         0 |   616,563     11,893 |   628,456 
         1 |   147,128     10,755 |   157,883 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |   763,691     22,648 |   786,339
```

Here is the regression and its results:

```
xtmixed units_sold **promotion** **display** **i.promotion#i.display** centsperbottle  light bottle i.pack new  b(2).categnew i.weeknew || iri_key:

note: 1.pr#0.majordisplay omitted because of collinearity                       
note: 1.pr#1.majordisplay omitted because of collinearity                       

Performing EM optimization:                         

Performing gradient-based optimization:                         

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -733657.04                          
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -733657.04                          

Computing standard errors:                      

Mixed-effects ML regression                     Number of obs      =    786339                      
Group variable: iri_key                         Number of groups   =      1272                      

                                                Obs per group: min =         1                      
                                                               avg =     618.2                      
                                                               max =      2072                      


                                                Wald chi2(68)      = 151765.04                      
Log likelihood = -733657.04                     Prob > chi2        =    0.0000                      


Units_sold           Coef.  Std. Err.   z   P>|z|   [95% Conf.  Interval]

Promotion           0.1035284   0.0019848   52.16   0   0.0996383   0.1074185
Display             0.3858362   0.0062404   61.83   0   0.3736052   0.3980671                           
Promotion#Display                       
   0 1             -0.003899    0.008403    -0.46   0.643   -0.0203685  0.0125706
   1 0              0 (omitted)             
   1 1              0 (omitted)
```

(The rest of the output is not included.)

It is ***not*** omitted, when I don't test for main effects.

Comment: what program is being used?

Comment: This is done in Stata.

Comment: Also, I am using here multilevel regression but regardless of the method, the result is still the same. The two category combinations are always omitted. I just need to understand why this happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question seems entirely specific to Stata. As such it does not fit at Cross Validated. Perhaps you could find some Stata forum for it.

Comment: Why do you think this is Stata-related?

Comment: This is a basic misunderstanding of indicator variables (dummy variables, in the awful terminology you've adopted) and in that sense is **not** specific to Stata. There are three parameters to estimate with two (0, 1) indicators and their interaction; you can't parameterise the whole thing with 5, which is what you are asking Stata to do. For Stata syntax study `help fvvarlist`

Comment: Did you notice the starred messages about multicollinearity?  They appear to fully answer your question.

Comment: [here](http://maartenbuis.nl/publications/ref_cat.html) are various examples of how to play with interactions with and without main effects. Once you understand those, you will understand the results you got from Stata.

Comment: Got it, I now understand the situation. Maarten's document was particularly useful.